# When specialization of template class is allowed with more template arguments than it's been declared?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

The code is very simple and concise (`YATC` means `yet another template class` `:)`)

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
class YATC; /*declaration*/

template<typename T1>
class YATC<T1,T1> {}; 

template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
class YATC<T1, YATC<T2, T3>> {};

int main()
{
    YATC<int, YATC<int, double>> yatc;
    return 0;
}
```

This black magic looks very disturbing for me.

- I declared the class as a template class **with two template arguments** `T1`,`T2`;
- I've expected that I **can make specializations** for `YATC` class based on idea that I can specificate definition of the class **on two template arguments only**;
- I've found out that actually I can make specialization using infinite template arguments like `typename T1, typename T2, typename T3` but with some interesting restrictions:
- I cannot use `std::common_type_t<T1, T2>` as second parameter for `YATC` specialization. The compiler throws an error that `T2` isn't used for `YATC`'s specialization;
- However, I can use them for using specialization with instance of some template class that receives these arguments (as `YATC<T2, T3>`);
- But! I still cannot instantiate the class with `YATC<int, int, double>`, only `YATC<int, YATC<int, double>>`;

**Why the such declaration is still valid but why I cannot instantiate the class with** `YATC<int, int, double>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've expected that I can make specializations for `YATC` class based on idea that I can specificate definition of the class on two template arguments only;

And this is correct.

> I've found out that actually I can make specialization using infinite template arguments like `typename T1, typename T2, typename T3` but with some interesting restrictions:

Yes... but still remain that `YACT` has only two template arguments

Take your second specialization

```
template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
class YATC<T1, YATC<T2, T3>> {};
```

You use three template parameter but `YACT` receive only two template arguments:

1. `T1`
2. `YACT<T2, T3>`

The second one is something complex, and is expressed through `YACT` itself and a couple of template parameters of the specializations, but `YACT<T2, T2>` remain a single template argument, from the `YACT` point of view.

Substantially, declaring

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
class YATC;
```

you declare that `YACT` receive exactly two types; nothing forbid you to construct your types in a very very complex way

```
//                1                                  2
//...vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv..vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
YACT<std::tuple<YACT<int, long>>, char>, std::vector<std::string>>> foo;
```

and declare `YACT` specializations that use a lot of template parameter (not only types but also values and template-template), to express the couple the `YACT` types parameter. But `YACT` has to receive **exaclty** two types parameters. Complex as you will but exactly two.

> I still cannot insatiate the class with `YATC<int, int, double>`, only `YATC<int, YATC<int, double>>`;

Exactly.

Because with

```
//    1    2      3
// ..VVV..VVV..VVVVVV
YATC<int, int, double>
```

you pass **three** types to `YACT`, but with

```
//    1           2
// ..VVV..VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV
YATC<int, YATC<int, double>>
```

you pass **two** types to `YACT` (`YACT<int, double>` is a single type).

Answer (score 3):

Because `YATC` is still declared to take two template arguments, despite the specialization misleading you to think otherwise.

It may help to think of the specializations as to be themselves templated. To give you an idea of what I mean, consider:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
class YATC;
```

A specialization of `YATC` here is constructed using two types - `T1` and `T2`.

```
template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
class YATC<T1, YATC<T2, T3>> {};
```

Here, it is true that the *specialization* has three template arguments - `T1`, `T2` and `T3`. However, `YATC` itself still only takes two template arguments - `T1` and `YATC<T2, T3>`.

So, to answer your question directly, declaring `template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3> class YATC<T1, YATC<T2, T3>>` does not actually declare `YATC` to be a template taking three arguments. The specialization itself, in a way, can be thought of as a template taking three arguments, though these arguments are always filled in implicitly when the specialization is constructed.